# Spring Boot CSRF fails when handled by Load balancer

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have implemented CSRF filter in spring boot by using header based token method. When I run on single server my applications works well, when I introduce another server or request that serverd by load balancer (depends on how load balancer serves request) it fails to validate the token given by the other server.

Can anyone here tell me that how can we create token for CSRF based on particular key which will be same for all server and every server will access that same key to identify the user, or some other way to share CSRF token within different server.

Comment: How do you create the tokens and how do you store them on the server ?

Comment: I have created token using CsrfToken.class.getName() by extending OncePerRequestFilter class of org.springframework.web.filter. Please note that I have not stored on server instead I am attaching that token with every request in header. Please tell me the best possible way to store token on server side. Thanks in advance

Comment: So in that case your token will be stored on the server in a session; Mahesh's answer explains how you can deal with this by either having sticky sessions or replicating sessions across your cluster.

Comment: PaulNUK as I have mention in below comment that I don't want to use any other server. From purely java or spring boot concept can I achieve what I want? Or any other solution for this so neither port or server will used? Thanks in advance

Comment: A third way is to write your own `CsrfTokenRepository` and save the token in a database, where it can be loaded from all servers.

Comment: store in database, it could impact to database performance? as you can see, it will insert to database every request. so, good idea to store in database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you can workaround this issue:

1. Configure your load balancer to use/work with sticky sessions.
   For example if you are using Nginx as a load balancer you can explore below links:

   - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html
   - https://aggarwalarpit.wordpress.com/2015/11/12/sticky-session-load-balancer-with-nginx/
2. If you do not want to use sticky sessions, then you can use Spring Session, as by default the CSRF token is stored inside the HTTP session.

   Hence you need to have the HTTP session replicated over. You can do this using Spring Session.

   Refer below links:

   - https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/
   - [https://blog.jayway.com/2015/05/31/scaling-out-with-sprin
     g-session/](https://blog.jayway.com/2015/05/31/scaling-out-with-spring-session/)

   You will need to have a Redis server installed.If not already installed you can follow below steps:

   **Redis**

   [Download](https://redis.io/) and install Redis. For example if you are using OS X you can use Brew, e.g.

   ```
    $ brew install redis
   ```

(If you use Linux, you can use `yum` or `apt-get`. Alternatively, read the Quick Start Guide.)

```
 Start Redis by calling the redis-server command, e.g. if you use Brew on OS X:

    $ redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf

 [...]

 Port: 6379

 [...]

 Server started, Redis version 3.0.1

 [...]
```

Comment: Thanks mahesh for answer, but my requirement is something like I don't want to install or engage any port of operating system. Can I do this type of session handling or say mechanism which you mention by using purely java concept?  If it is possible please let me know. Thanks in advance.